# Passing argument to React Apollo mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-hooks

I'm having issues where a mutation appears to not send any of the arguments. My mutation appears to be correct, insomuch that the error I receive from the server is that it isn't finding the user rather than an issue with the syntax, e.g. 400.

```
export const LOGIN = gql`
    mutation signIn($email: String!, $password: String!){
        signIn(login: $email, password: $password) {
            token
        }
    }
`;
```

I've confirmed that the variables are correct in local state. I've also confirmed that sending the credentials via the Apollo DevTools returns the correct token. Here is the relevant bit of the mutation.

```
<Mutation
    mutation={LOGIN}
    variables={{
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password
    }}
    onError={(e) => {
        console.log(state.auth); // to confirm the state data is correct
        console.log(e);
    }}
    update={(store, { data }) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'login',
            value: data.token
        })
    }}
>
```

At this point I'm stumped and frustrated. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT - this appears to be stranger than I anticipated. If I hardcode the values into the variables argument of the mutation, it works correctly.

```
variables={{
    email: "some-valid-email@website.com",
    password: "some-valid-password"
}}
```

Yet when I pass the data in from the state, which happens through useContext, it breaks.

```
const context = React.useContext(AppContext);
console.log(context.auth.email, context.auth.password); // logs the same valid email and password
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Apollo and React.useContext (or useReducer)

If I have context such as:

```
const context = React.useContext(AppContext);
```

and I pass the context (which contains the email/password) to the GraphQL variable such as:

```
        variables={context.auth}
```

...it works.

However instantiating the variables separately doesn't seem to work.

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
let email = context.auth.email
let password = context.auth.password

variables={{email, password}}
```

Is this a gotcha? I'm not certain. But at least I have a workaround for the time being.